# Visual Studio 2017 equivalent of Resharper's Alt+\ "Show file members"?

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I'm trying very hard to use 2017 without Resharper. The native Go-to is slow and screams to 50% CPU anytime I start typing in it, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> is just a more burdensome version of R#'s <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> (and there is no good equivalent of R#'s <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd>)...

The only replacement for <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> I've found is mapping "View.SynchronizeClassView" to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>, which gives focus to the Class View and navigates to the active class.

Is there like... a better alternative than this?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here in the Help Center. Perhaps [Software Recommendation](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Frederic: They're not asking for software recommendations, though, they're asking for help with their existing development tools? Still don't know whether this is classed as on-topic, but that seems like the wrong place to send them to.

Comment: I'll just ask reddit or something it's coo